# Error processing policy updates

Tags: 2013, custom-list, timer-jobs

I've seen error event with Event ID 7997 in the Event log. Task category is Information Policy Management.

Error processing policy updates for site http://site for list *listname*.

> Error:  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>   at Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.InformationPolicy.ListPolicySettings.get_UseListPolicy()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.InformationPolicy.Policy.<>c__DisplayClass5.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__1(SPList
>   list)    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Utilities.ContentIterator.ProcessLists(SPListCollection
>   lists, ListProcessor listProcessor, ListProcessorErrorCallout
>   errorCallout)

List *listname* is a part of custom feature.

Initial analysis points to *Information management policy timer* job.

What could be the cause of this error?

EDIT:
Inner exception is `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.` SQL Server stored procedure: `proc_GetDocsMetaInfo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in `ListTemplate` element, `Type` attribute value was set to a number greater than 10,000,000 in the `Elements.xml` for list definition. I reduced the value and error wasn't present any more.

For future reference, this must be obeyed:
`BaseType` + `Type` * 256 < 2^31 - 1

This means if `BaseType` == 0, `Type` must be less than 8,388,607.

Additional analysis: https://slavensemper.blogspot.com/2019/09/error-processing-policy-updates.html